# SQL stored yyyy/mm/dd to text via php/sql

Tags: php, mysql

My date field currently saves data in the following format:

2016-09-02 14:04:43

Instead, I'd like it to say:

02 September 2016, 2:04 PM

Is there an easy way to convert it using PHP/MySQL statements?

**EDIT:**
I would like to also be able to select let's say the rows where the date is in the last 30 days. For example, select all rows where date is > 2017/03/06

Comment: You should make the column DATETIME and not worry about how it's stored. You just need to worry about how it's *displayed*, which you can deal with in your SELECT.

Comment: I have a column called DATE, and it's stored like above, when I echo it, it's displayed exactly like it's stored

Comment: I said **type**, not **named**. Make the column DATATYPE a DATETIME, not a CHAR() or VARCHAR(), and it's stored internally in a pre-set format that you don't need to worry about.

Comment: I see, it's now  datetime but it's still echoing non-formatted type. Will I need to add CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE()) sort of thing at the end of my $sql query?

Comment: Where's the PHP code where you are trying to echo it?

Comment: In the wordpress setting, I find the user by $user->wp_get_current_user(); echo $user->date_registered;

Comment: You format it when displaying (echoing) it to look like whatever you want.

Comment: Do  I need to do http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php ?

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I need to use date() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function: `date_format()`.
In your case, you can try:

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %M %Y %h:%i %p)`

more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Also do the change people have told you, make the column datetime.